# Screen Capture in ffmpeg with jerky movement

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to capture a portion of my screen, save it as a movie file, and stream it to a Youtube live event.
The result is a jerky movement. The log has some issues I'm not able to understand and solve. I did a lot of different try, but with no result.

This is the actual Command line I use:

```
"C:\\mbiWebTV\\programs\\ffmpeg\\bin_x86\\ffmpeg.exe" 
-thread_queue_size 512 -report -re -rtbufsize 2000M -f dshow 
-i "audio=Missaggio stereo (Realtek High Definition Audio)" 
-f dshow 
-i "video=screen-capture-recorder" -filter:v "crop=713:379:018:043" 
-s 848x480 -video_size 848x480 -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast 
-maxrate 6000 -bufsize 2000M -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 60 -acodec libmp3lame 
-b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 
-f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxx-xyyv-0rrm-f9g2 
-filter:v "crop=713:379:018:043" 
"c:\\mbiWebTV\\Capture\\Capture_20170225_165829.mkv"
```

I could send the complete log file. 
This is the error messages that frequently occurs:

> [dshow @ 049a4240] real-time buffer [screen-capture-recorder] [video
>   input] too full or near too full (545% of size: 3041280 [rtbufsize
>   parameter])! frame dropped!

---

Answer (score 2):

The `rtbufsize` is only affecting the audio.

Try

```
ffmpeg.exe
-thread_queue_size 512 -report -rtbufsize 100M -f dshow -i "audio=Missaggio stereo (Realtek High Definition Audio)"
-rtbufsize 1000M -thread_queue_size 512 -video_size 848x480 -f dshow -i "video=screen-capture-recorder"
-vf "crop=713:379:18:43,scale=848:480,setsar=1"
-vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -maxrate 6M -bufsize 12M -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 60
-acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100
-f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxx-xyyv-0rrm-f9g2
-filter:v "crop=713:379:18:43" "c:\mbiWebTV\Capture\Capture_20170225_165829.mkv"
```

Comment: I changed only the position of  -video_size 848x480 parameter and it worked very well.

Comment: The laptop I use is an Intel I7, now I made the same test on a different laptop (intel celeron) and after few second I get real-time buffer too full or near too full .

Comment: Output file #1 (c:\mbiWebTV\Capture\Capture_20170225_AAAAAA.mkv):
  Output stream #1:0 (video): 222 frames encoded; 222 packets muxed (366088 bytes); 
  Output stream #1:1 (audio): 10680 frames encoded (683520 samples); 670 packets muxed (199011 bytes); 
  Total: 892 packets (565099 bytes) muxed
253 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
dshow passing through packet of type video size  8392758 timestamp

Comment: dshow passing through packet of type video size  8392758 timestamp 11976436850000 orig timestamp 11976436850000 graph timestamp 11976436850000 diff 0 screen-capture-recorder
[dshow @ 04472460] real-time buffer [screen-capture-recorder] [video input] too full or near too full (86% of size: 1000000000 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
dshow passing through packet of type video size  8392758 timestamp 11976437520000 orig timestamp 11976437520000 graph timestamp 11976437520000 diff 0 screen-capture-recorder

Comment: You'll have to increase the rtbufsize.just before the video (provided you have enough ram).